# Desktop Randomly Disconnects from Wireless Internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-card

Perplexing problem that's been bugging me for week - recently my desktop computer has been randomly disconnecting from the wifi. All the other devices in the apartment are working fine with no problem / no dropped connection (2 phones, 2 laptops, 2 work laptops, 1 tablet, chromecast).

I've been trying to troubleshoot his for quite awhile and tried a few different things:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled wireless driver
- Updated wireless driver
- Changed router channel to a less noisy channel
- Disabled the ability for the computer to turn off the wireless card to save power

When it disconnects, all I have to do is reconnect to the network and it works fine after a few moments. This can happen infrequently (handful of times per day) or frequently (multiple times per hour).

This started happening right after moving apartments - before my desktop was literally inches away from the router but now it's in a different room. The router has also changed. I would just plug an ethernet cable but this apartment doesn't have a wired network built in the walls. Actually, this is the furthest my desktop has been from a router / the first place I couldn't use an ethernet cable.

I'm using Windows 10, 64-bit Operating System, and a RaLink Dual Stream 802.11n Wireless LAN Card.

I'm suspecting a need a better wireless card but would like to make sure before spending the $$.

Thanks!

Comment: You could move the PC near to the router and check. If it works without any problems, then the problem was the distance.